# Splitting on $p$ adic unit group

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, local-field

Let $p$ be a prime.

It is basic that following isomorphisms;

$\mathbb{Z}_p^{\times}/(1+p^n\mathbb{Z}_p )\cong (\mathbb{Z}_p/p^n\mathbb{Z}_p)^{\times} $,

$(1+p^n\mathbb{Z}_p)/(1+p^{n+1}\mathbb{Z}_p )\cong \mathbb{Z}_p/p\mathbb{Z}_p$

But I don’t figure out why those split i.e.

(1) $\mathbb{Z}_p^{\times}\cong(1+p^n\mathbb{Z}_p )\times(\mathbb{Z}_p/p^n\mathbb{Z}_p)^{\times} $,

(2)
$1+p^n\mathbb{Z}_p\cong(1+p^{n+1}\mathbb{Z}_p )\times \mathbb{Z}_p/p\mathbb{Z}_p$.

Comment: There is a short exact sequence $\def\Z{\mathbb{Z}}0 \to 1 + p^n \Z_p \to \Z_p^\times \to (\Z_p/p^n \Z_p)^\times \to 0$ coming from reduction mod $p$. This sequence splits for $n=1$ (or $p=2, n=2$) with the [*Teichmüller lift*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teichm%C3%BCller_character).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get this off the unanswered list: Except in very few exceptional cases, neither of your isomorphisms (1) nor (2) is true. I.e. those sequences, in general, **do not** split.

The few cases where they do split are exhibited by Johann Birnick in a comment.

In fact, the only torsion elements i.e. roots of unity in the multiplicative group $\mathbb Q_p^\times$ are well-known to be

$\{\pm 1\}$ for $p=2$, and $\mu_{p-1}$ (the $p-1$-th roots of unity) for odd $p$.

But the group on the RHS of you proposed iso (1) has elements of order $p^n-p^{n-1}$, and the group on the RHS of your proposed iso (2) has elements of order $p$.

This excludes iso (1) for $n\ge 2$ if $p$ odd, for $n \ge 3$ if $p=2$; and it excludes iso (2) for all odd $p$.

Finally, to exclude iso (2) for $p=2$ and $n \ge 2$, just note that the torsion element $-1$ is not in $1+2^n \mathbb Z_2$ for any $n \ge 2$, i.e. that subgroup cannot contain more torsion elements than the trivial $+1$, certainly cannot have a subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb Z/2$.

Comment: Would you mind if I ask you the reason? I’m not familiar with p adic number very well sorry.

Comment: @user682141: See edit.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! It immediately follows from $1+p^n\mathbb{Z}$ has torsion $\iff n=1,p=2$ that $n=1,p=2$ for (2) to hold, and it follows from a simple group theory consideration that in that case (2) holds.I have seen that (1) can only occur in the case Johann Birnick wrote by comparing the group structure of the torsion subgroups on both sides (but "(1) has elements of order $p^n-p^{n-1}$" is wrong when $p=2,n\geq 3$).